# javascript:window.print() prints 2 pages while I have 1

Tags: javascript, css, printing

I have a simple HTML document which includes an image tag only.
I want to print the image after document's loaded.
my code:

```
<body>    
    <img id="form1" src="form1.jpg" alt="form1" style="margin: 0 auto;display:block;" onLoad="javascript:window.print()" />
</body>
```

it works but the problem is that it prints both the image ( webpage ) and another paper which is empty and only has a text on top which is giving the address of image and html title. how can I prevent from printing the extra paper ?

P.S : I used jquery plugins like PrintElement.js, jqPrint.js, etc, but they have same problem...

Comment: You can use CSS for controlling the image size, etc for print -  using `@media print
  {
  /* your print conditions here. */
  }`

Comment: how can i remove the second paper by '@media print' options ?

Comment: Give the image a `max-width`. That way, you can control how the image renders on the page. Example: `@media print { body img {width: 90%; max-width: 1048px; } }`

Comment: It worked, thank you so much karthikr <3

Comment: great.. Making this an answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS for controlling the image size, etc for print - using `@media print`

Give the image a `max-width`.

That way, you can control how the image renders on the page. Example:

```
@media print { 
    body img {
       width: 90%; max-width: 1048px; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scale down the image a little bit and center it with margin.

```
<img src="form1.jpg" width="90%" style="margin:auto;"/>
```

Comment: the image is completely inside the first page, the second page is something which is not related to the image I guess... the second paper includes the html file address only like files:///C:/Users/.../index.html

Answer (score 0):

You Can Make a iframe tag by js and Put Image On it Then Print only iframe.

I hope it Work

```
<iframe id="iframeprint" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

maybe You Need This js Code

access To inside Of iframe

```
document.getElementById('iframeprint').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML=document.getElementById('form1');
```

print iframe only

```
document.getElementById('iframeprint').contentWindow.print() ;
```